# SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_FOREIGNKEY en JAVA no consigo capturarla

Tags: java, sqlite, excepciones, jdbc

Hola muy buenas que tal , espero que bien.
Me gustaría consultar con vosotros una duda que me ha surgido y que he buscado por todo internet sin resultado alguno.
Estoy haciendo una practica de clase, y estamos conectando JDBC con SQLite.
Mi problema es que cuando intento insertar datos con claves ajenas, si no existen tales registros con esas claves, evidentemente me tira la excepción, pero claro me gustaría poder capturarla tratarla y mostrar un mensaje con mis propias palabras que me indique cual ha sido el error. La excepción que me lanza es **`SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_FOREIGNKEY`** y con el método `getErrorCode()` devuelvo el código, pero es genérico no es concretamente la excepción que me tira.Si concierais alguna forma de poder capturar concretamente la excepción **`SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_FOREIGNKEY`**, os lo agradecería mucho.
Igual es tontería ya que SQLite es embebida y supongo que no es tan importante, pero soy del tipo de persona que me gusta perfeccionar cualquier programa aun que no tenga mucha utilidad, y así consigo mejorar constantemente y aprender cosas nuevas.
Muchas Gracias y un saludo.

Comment: Hola. Muestra tu código Java donde haces la consulta para poder ayudarte. El tipo de excepción a capturar en este caso es `SQLException`, [revisa la documentación para más detalles](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/sqlexception.html). Pulsa en [edit] para completar la pregunta.

Comment: Lo sé, sé que la Excepción que lanza es SQLException, pero hay tantas que lo me gustaría amí es conseguir capturar una en concreto. En estos momentos no tengo problema de código sino que no encuentro la manera de remplazar el mensaje generado por la excepción SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_FOREIGNKEY, por un mensaje propio, no se si me he explicado bien..Ya lo siento. Pero muchas gracias por tu comentario.

Comment: Lo más simple es crear tu propia clase que extienda de `SQLException`, usas esa clase y dentro de ella declaras el mensaje personalizado según el código de cada excepción.

Comment: Vale muchas gracias, me ha servido!